# JAXB more than one possible root element

Tags: xml, jaxb

I need to bind an XML response using JAXB. however, there are two possible responses, either the success XML or error XML. So, I need a way to receive either one. Below are two sample XML files. I'd appreciate it, if anyone could help me with this. I've been looking everywhere how to do achieve to good solution! Thanks!!

Successful response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResponseEnvioComandoSpy>
<comandoSpy>
<id>5</id>
<status>4</status>
<erro>0</erro>
</comandoSpy>
</ResponseEnvioComandoSpy>
```

Error response

```
<ErrorRequest>
<codigo>14</codigo>
<erro>Nenhum comando/macro a ser enviada, favor verificar as tags xml.</erro>
<request>EnvioComando</request>
</ErrorRequest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `@XmlElementDecl` on a class annotated with `@XmlResistry` (usually `ObjectFactory` for this use case)

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html

Comment: Hi Blaise! Thank you for your quick response! I Couldn't help notice that Ive already read a bunch of posts on your blog. But I just came across another one of your posts which talks about MOXy. Do you think it would be worth my while to use EclipseLink MOXy for this project as i have many xml requests may have up to 5 different xml responses. Thanks!

Comment: @user2682868 - I always recommend people use MOXy as their JAXB (JSR-222) provider (I'm the MOXy lead).  When possible you should leverage the standard APIs, this gives you the most flexibility when choosing a provider.

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks to Blaise's tutorial http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html ive managed to solve my problem. The solution was to implement an object factory with the classes of both xml's. Heres the code below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
    RequestMensagemCB requestMensagemCB = new RequestMensagemCB();
    XMLBinder xmlBinder = new XMLBinder();
    InputStreamReader isr = Request.doPost(url, xmlBinder.marshaller(requestMensagemCB));


    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();

    Object object = (Object) unmarshaller.unmarshal(isr);
    Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    marshaller.marshal(object, System.out);
}

@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

public ObjectFactory() {
}

public ResponseMensagemCB createResponseMensagemCB() {
    return new ResponseMensagemCB();
}

public ErrorRequest createErrorRequest() {
    return new ErrorRequest();
}
}
```